# How do I make two different @Providers inject the same @Singleton in Dagger 2?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Considering the following scenario:

```
public class SessionManager implements HasSession, HasCredentials{
/**implementation here*/
}
```

I've defined a SessionModule to inject SessionManager whenever HasSession or HasCredentials is requested for injection:

```
@Module
public abstract class SessionModule {
    @Provides @Singleton static HasSession hasSession(SessionManager sessionManager){
        return sessionManager;
    };

    @Provides @Singleton static HasCredentials hasCredentials(SessionManager sessionManager){
        return sessionManager;
    };
}
```

Then I've defined the corresponding component:

```
@Component(modules={SessionModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface MyComponent {

    public HasSession getSessionProvider();

    public HasCredentials getCredentialsProvider();

}
```

getSessionProvider and getCredentialsProvider will create/return two different SessionManager instance.

I would like a **single** instance of SessionManager to be created and returned whenever I call getSessionProvider or getCredentialsProvider. How can I acomplish that with Dagger 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem: Just defining a Singleton provider for SessionManager:

```
@Provides @Singleton
static SessionManager sessionManager(/*dependencies here*/){
    return new SessionManager(/**dependencies*/);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two separate things:

1. Scope the binding so that there's only one instance.
2. Alias the scoped binding to the alternate types.

First, scope the binding:

```
@Qualifier
private @interface Scoped {}

@Provides @Singleton
@Scoped SessionManager scopeSessionManager(SessionManager manager) {
  return manager;
}
```

Second, alias the scoped binding:

```
@Binds abstract HasSession bindHasSession(@Scoped SessionManager manager);
@Binds abstract HasCredentials bindHasCredentials(@Scoped SessionManager manager);
```

*Note:* This will not prevent modules in this component from using the unscoped `SessionManager`, so be careful.

An easy way to workaround that is to use a `@Component.Builder` and use `@BindsInstance` to pass in a single instance of `SessionManager` that's *effectively* scoped (and thus eliminating the need for the first code snippet above and allowing your original code to work).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jake. I gave it a try and worked but I want to avoid using Quilifiers when they are not needed. If I had two different implementations of the same interface I'd go for it.
I found a solution that is quite trivial.